# Hibernate PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have user_roles table with foreign key with user table and roles as follows

[image]

After creating the POJO I have the following classes

```
Users
Roles
UserRoles
  +private Users users
  +private Roles roles
  +private UserRolesId id
UserRolesId
```

I want create Save two table information Map

```
  public List<UserRolesJOIN> getUserRoles(String websiteID) {
        sf.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        return sf.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(UserRoles.class, "ur")
                .createAlias("ur.users", "login")
                .createAlias("ur.roles", "roles")
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(UserRolesJOIN.class))
                .list();
    }


class UserRolesJOIN
  +login,roles with set/get
```

Error : 
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for ur

```
at org.hibernate.property.ChainedPropertyAccessor.getSetter(ChainedPropertyAccessor.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.initialize(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.transformTuple(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CriteriaLoader.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:753)
```

Comment: So are you sure that your UserRoles class has needed setters?

Comment: Thank you I checked again and found the setter in UserRoles JOIN is not needed

Comment: But I still have not dealt with my problem hoping you help

Comment: Check this link https://vladmihalcea.com/2017/04/03/why-you-should-use-the-hibernate-resulttransformer-to-customize-result-set-mappings/.